# Check is the structure is empty (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a special class of objects and some method which returns me structures such as:

```
{'items': [{'_from': 12,
            'bla': 3713,
            'ff': 0.0,
            'd': 45755,
            'fdef': 1536},
           {'_from': None,
            'bla': 3712,
            'ff': 0.0,
            'd': 45838,
            'fdef': 1536}]}
```

Sometimes this structure is empty and then I get the following;

```
{'items': []}
```

How can I check in my program if the returning structure is empty? It has no such attributes as length. It seems that I can access single elements of the structure only via the Loop (so nothing like `structure['items']['bla']` is possible):

```
for k in myStructure.items:
         idd=k.bla
```

How can I perform such a check in an elegant way?

Comment: What about `if k:`?

Answer (score 1):

Empty `list`s evaluate to `False` when used in an if-statement.

```
if myStructure.items:
    for k in myStructure.items:
         idd=k.bla
```

Example:

```
>>> if []: 
    print('here')


>>> 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate directly over values. As I show below, you can  get the length of the empty list, which is 0, or you can simply use `if i` which will be `True` if the list is not empty.

```
myStructure = {'items': []}

for i in myStructure.values():
    if not i:
        print ("list is empty")
    print (len(i))
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'BlaBlaBla' has no len()

Comment: does not return anything :(

Comment: Can you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)